# Collapsing Folder Trees with Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

This is a quick script I whipped up to collapse some folder trees down to individual folders. The specific situation that arose was my formerly-itunes collection (it's currently organized `Music\artist\album\songs.(mp3|m4a)` and I'd really prefer it to be `Music\artist\song.(mp3|m4a)`).

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'optparse'
require 'pp'
require 'fileutils'

### parsing command line options via optparse, nothing to see here
options={}
optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|
  opts.on('-h', '--help', 
          'Display this screen') do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
  opts.on('-t', '--type a,b,c', 
          Array, 'Specify filetypes to flatten out (defaults to mp3,m4a)') do|t|
    options[:types] = t
  end
end
optparse.parse!

### the setup (ideally, this would be in a `let` statement)
origin = Dir.pwd
if not options[:types]
  options[:types] = ["mp3", "m4a"]
end

### the actual work
ARGV.each do |target|
  FileUtils.cd("#{origin}/#{target}")
  options[:types].each{|ext| `find -iname '*.#{ext}' -exec mv {} ./ \\\;`}
  `find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \\\;`
end
FileUtils.cd(origin)
```

Am I doing anything eye-stabbingly wrong? Is there a better way of handling any of the above?

Specifically, I suspect that I could replace the find calls with native Ruby methods, but I can't see how without complicating it significantly. I also suspect that there's a better way of writing `FileUtils.cd("#{origin}/#{target}")`, but a cursory reading of [Dir](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html) doesn't reveal anything. Any tips?

---

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'optparse'
require 'pp'
require 'fileutils'

### parsing command line options via optparse
options={:types => ["mp3", "m4a"]}
optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|
  opts.on('-h', '--help', 'Display this screen') do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
  opts.on('-t', '--type a,b,c', Array, 'Specify filetypes to flatten out (comma separated, defaults to mp3,m4a)') do|t|
    options[:types] = t
  end
end
optparse.parse!

### the actual work
ARGV.each do |target|
  FileUtils.cd(target) do
    options[:types].each{|ext| `find -iname '*.#{ext}' -exec mv {} ./ \\\;`} ##move all matched files into [target]
    `find -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \\\;` ##recursively delete all empty folders in [target]
  end
end
```

- `options` is now initialized beforehand rather than being checked after `.parse!`
- using the block option on `FileUtils.cd`
- removed useless final `cd` back
- tried the `glob` option, but it just errors without continuing if it hits a matched file in `target` (ie. one that needs to stay where it is). This seems to happen when I pass `:force => TRUE` too. The `find` call notes such files, but still flattens what it can. The `glob` route also doesn't seem to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
options={}
# ...
if not options[:types]
  options[:types] = ["mp3", "m4a"]
end
```

I would initialize `options` with the default values first, instead of checking whether the option is set afterwards. I.e.

```
options = {:types => ["mp3", "m4a"]}
```

---

```
options[:types].each{|ext| `find -iname '*.#{ext}' -exec mv {} ./ \\\;`}
```

This can be done with a glob. For this I'd first change `options[:types]` to be string (i.e. replace `Array` with `String` in the optparse code and use `"mp3,m4a"` instead of `["mp3", "m4a"]` as the default. Then you can use `Dir.glob` with `FileUtils.mv` like this:

```
Dir.glob("**/*.{#{ ext }}") {|f| FileUtils.mv(f, ".")}
```

---

> I suspect that I could replace the find calls with native Ruby methods, but I can't see how without complicating it significantly.

For the first one see above. However the second one would indeed be more complicated to replace, so I'd just stick with the `find` call.

---

> I also suspect that there's a better way of writing `FileUtils.cd("#{origin}/#{target}")`

Yes, there is: `cd` optionally takes a block. When given a block, `cd` will cd into the given directory, execute the block, and then cd back. So you can get rid of `origin` and just do

```
FileUtils.cd(target) do
  ...
end
```

---

```
FileUtils.cd(origin)
```

Even without using the block version of `cd` the above line would be completely unnecessary. Changing the directory at the end of a script has no effect. Any cd performed in a process will never affect the parent process.